# Setting the name of a text-field to the option selected from a drop-down list

Tags: php, html

```
             <form action="<?php echo $self ?>" method="post">
                <br>
                    <select name="choice" id="choice">
                          <option value="product" name="product">Product</option>            
                          <option value="saab">Brand</option>
                          <option value="mercedes">Price</option>
                          <option value="audi">Name</option>
                    </select>
            <br>
                   search :<input name="<?php $choice=$_POST['choice'];?>" type="text" value="<?php $choice ?>"><br>



                    <br><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
            </form>
```

What i want to do is get the value from my dropdown list and set the to the value of my textfield dont want to use java script

i want the value selected from "choice" to be the name of my textarea search seen below the

Anyhelp is greatly apperciated
thanks

Comment: You must have to use `JS` to do what you want

Comment: IS it difficult to do

Comment: infact, why are you creating that `<input name="<?php $choice=$_POST['choice'];?>...` you do not need actually

You can get the selected value with `$_POST['choice']` at backend PHP and do whatver

Comment: Because i want my  <input name="<?php $choice=$_POST['choice'];?>. to search my database according to what criteria is selected in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment

> Because i want my . to search my database according to what criteria is selected in the dropdown menu

I will still say that you do not need `<input name="<?php $choice=$_POST['choice'];?>` in your code ...

When the Form is submitted, the selected value of that `select` list is also submitted with form. As your `<select>`'s `name` attribute value is `choice`, you can get the selected value with `$_POST['choice']` in your PHP script.

```
<form action="<?php echo $self ?>" method="post">
    <br>
    <select name="choice" id="choice">
        <option value="product" name="product">Product</option>            
        <option value="saab">Brand</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Price</option>
        <option value="audi">Name</option>
    </select>
    <?php
    $value_to_show = (isset($_POST['choice']) && !empty($_POST['choice'])) ? $_POST['choice'] : "";
    ?>
  <input name="<?php echo $value_to_show ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $value_to_show ?>"><br>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

For example. If I select `<option value="saab">Brand</option>` and submit the form, then `$_POST['choice']` value will be `saab`

Hope it helps

Comment: I still having trouble with it does $_POST['choice go in myform or the if(isset['submit']) {} ?

Comment: if(isset['submit']) {  echo $_POST['choice'];  }

Comment: selected value is in `$_POST['choice']`

Test it with `echo $_POST['choice'];`

Comment: ye that works how would i assign the selected item to the name and value of my <input>

Comment: <input name="<?php echo $_POST['choice']; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['choice']; ?>"><br>

Comment: see in the answer too

Comment: I am getting this error <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: userid in <b>C:\Users\Andrew C\Documents\Programs\Webserver 8\root\Assignment_2015\index.php</b> on line <b>138</b><br />

Comment: `userid ` is not in your question ... this is something else ... post your all code

Comment: ye im getting somewhere now but say for example i select price from my drop menu then type 2.99 in to my input field i want to display things that are 2.99 from my database how ever it is not picking up that i typed 2.99 into my input field

Comment: You are really confused ... you want to write `SELECT` list selected value into input field and then you want to change that input field too :P

Comment: is that hard to do my head is all over the place with this  your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: di i put the selected value in to the input filed using php or html ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $prod = trim(isset($_REQUEST['prod'])) ? $_REQUEST['prod'] : '';
        $brand = trim(isset($_REQUEST['brand'])) ? $_REQUEST['brand'] : '';
        $prodname = trim(isset($_REQUEST['prodname'])) ? $_REQUEST['prodname'] : '';
        $price = trim(isset($_REQUEST['price'])) ? $_REQUEST['price'] : '';

       if(isset($_REQUEST['userid'])){
             $userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];
                                    }

        echo $userid;


        <form action="<?php echo $self ?>" method="post">
            <br>

            <select name="userid" id="userid" >
                  <option value="Criteria" name="Criteria">Select Criteria</option>
                  <option value="prod" name="prod">Product</option>
                  <option value="brand" name="brand">Brand</option>
                  <option value="price" name="price">Price</option>
                  <option value="prodname" name="prodname">Name</option>
            </select>


            <br>
                   search :<input name="<?php echo $_REQUEST['userid']; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['userid']; ?>"  ><br>



                    <br><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
            </form>
```